# Azure VM Core vs vCPU

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, cpu-cores

When comparing two different VM series in Azure, I see that one has Cores and the other one vCPUs. Keeping aside the number of Cores/CPUs, Memory and Processor Type (Intel Xeon E/Platinum etc), what is the advantage of one over the other? I understand that CPU can have multiple cores, but in Azure what is the difference between 4 vCPUs and 4 vCores?

**G Series with Core**
[image]
**D Series with vCPU** 
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A core is a physical unit of a CPU.

A virtual CPU (vCPU) also known as a virtual processor, is a physical central processing unit (CPU) that is assigned to a virtual machine (VM).

For more details, you can refer to these msdn answers: [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6ef016d8-9a53-4041-93bf-dc61a8665e3d/what-is-the-difference-in-core-and-vcpu?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5a2a0e1b-8439-4c43-ae7f-11c50ad94cb0/difference-between-azure-vm-core-and-vcpu?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).